# Android : apache HttpComponents Core

Tags: java, android, androidhttpclient

I want to add `org.apache.http` to my project and i downloaded and added it to my project , i developed some codes for testing , but when i removing `org.apache.http` from my project , my codes works fine , is added `org.apache.http` by default in android SDK and There is no need to add it to project?

```
public class ElementalHttpGet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpProcessor httpproc = HttpProcessorBuilder.create()
            .add(new RequestContent())
            .add(new RequestTargetHost())
            .add(new RequestConnControl())
            .add(new RequestUserAgent("Test/1.1"))
            .add(new RequestExpectContinue(true)).build();

        HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();

        HttpCoreContext coreContext = HttpCoreContext.create();
        HttpHost host = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080);
        coreContext.setTargetHost(host);

        DefaultBHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultBHttpClientConnection(8 * 1024);
        ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy = DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE;

        try {
            String[] targets = {
                "/",
                "/servlets-examples/servlet/RequestInfoExample",
                "/somewhere%20in%20pampa"};

            for (int i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
                if (!conn.isOpen()) {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), host.getPort());
                    conn.bind(socket);
                }
                BasicHttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest("GET", targets[i]);
                System.out.println(">> Request URI: " + request.getRequestLine().getUri());

                httpexecutor.preProcess(request, httpproc, coreContext);
                HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(request, conn, coreContext);
                httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, coreContext);

                System.out.println("<< Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                System.out.println("==============");
                if (!connStrategy.keepAlive(response, coreContext)) {
                    conn.close();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection kept alive...");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `org.apache.http` is part of the Android API.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html

But it seems to be a fork of an outdated versión of Apache HttpClient: 
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html

Comment: This added in SDK 20?

Comment: No, seems that it has been there since the first versión. The reference API indicates "Added in API level 1"